# shortcut for injecting strings with spring

Tags: java, spring

I inject Strings in my spring config by doing the following:

```
<bean class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Region" />
</bean>
```

Is there a shorter way of doing it?

**Update:**
I am using spring 3.0.3.

These are actually used to populate a list:

```
        <list>
            <bean class="java.lang.String">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Region" />
            </bean>
            ...
```

Seems like this works:

```
<list>
   <value>Region</value>
   <value>Name</value>
   ....
```

But I agree with the suggestions that this should eventually go in a property and be passed in.

Comment: Which version of Spring?

Comment: How are you using this? Can't you just use `value="Region"` in place of this bean?

Comment: Isn't that illegal doping?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not have `String` beans. Just use their value directly.

Create a properties file `strings.properties` and put it on the classpath

```
strings.key=Region
```

Declare a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>strings.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then annotate instance field Strings as

```
@Value("${strings.key}")
private String key;
```

Spring will inject the value from the `strings.properties` file into this `key` String.

This obviously assumes that the class in which the `@Value` annotation appears is a bean managed in the same context as the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: Note that you can use `@Value` also on constructor parameters.

Comment: I don't see how this is shorter and more effective way than simply beaning a String class thro the String constructor as already performed by asker. What's the point?

Comment: @BlessedGeek For one, you shouldn't consider a `String` as a _bean_. Spring wouldn't really manage the lifecycle of a `String` as it would, say, some `@Service` class instance. You should consider the primitive types, `String`, and `Class` as base types handled by Spring, not as beans. Once you have the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` declared, you can declare as many properties as you want (instead of `<bean>` declarations) and refer to them with the placeholder notation `${..}`.

Comment: @BlessedGeek As for implementation details, you no longer need the full Spring object tree required to manage a `<bean>` declaration. All you need is one `Properties` object (ymmv) per declared source (you can have more than one `location`).

Comment: see http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/74407-how-to-inject-property-value-from-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-in-another-bean for help if your string ends up with a value of the ${your.prop} instead of the actual property

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to create a bean of type `String`. Just pass the value to `constructor-arg`:

```
<bean id="foo" class="x.y.Foo">
    <constructor-arg value="Region"/>
</bean>
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers and if you're using Spring 3.1+, you can use the constructor namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" <-- add c namespace
  ...

<bean id="someClass" class="a.b.c.SomeClass"
  c:someProperty="Region"
/>
```